# How to Install 64-bit Adobe Photoshop CC in Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, ubuntu-gnome, photoshop

I am using a 64bit UbuntuGnome system and installed the Wine and Playonlinux. When I try to install the above mentioned version of Photoshop, I get an error that 'Cannot install a 64bit version in 32bit system'
So somehow the wine and playonlinux is configured in a way that they are treating the system as a 32bit instead of 64bit

Answer (score 0):

run `WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 winecfg` 
set up wine how you like, version, etc. then run `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 wine 64bitprogramsetup.exe` to install your 64 bit program